# WebApi how to get DisplayName from ModelStateDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Inside WebApi I have a viewmodel:

```
public class SignupVm
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("hehe")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Accessing ModelState in my controller, I cannot find a reference to the DisplayName attribute value. I'm trying to create my own custom error message array to serialise.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, typeof(SignupVm), "Name");
string displayName = metaData.DisplayName;
```

Comment: Interestingly this didn't work for me, not sure if that just because I was inside a custom validator.